# Connecting to a linux system using a Windows IDE for a C/C++ project

Tags: c++, c, centos, ide, visual-studio-2017

I am new to Linux and therefore feel difficult to code and develop in Linux based environment (CentOS).

Although coding is still fine,  I find debugging a quite challenging task because of the lack of breakpoints and the ease of navigating through various class, function and variable definitions that we can do in the blink of an eye using Windows/Mac IDE's.

This leads me to the question :

1. Can I use a windows IDE to connect to my Linux system and import my project repository and develop on it?

   I did [some research](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/14/bring-your-existing-c-linux-projects-to-visual-studio/) on using Visual Studio 2017 for this purpose and found a few articles, but most of them explain how I start up with a new project rather than importing/developing upon an existing project.

   I also had a look at an article that mentioned about Visual GDB but it wasn't very clear to me, so any pointers on how I can use that would be great.
2. Any other IDE that I can use on windows for the same purpose? (Visual studio is just something that I looked into, but any other suggestions are also welcome.)

**NOTE**: My project has both C and C++ code (networking domain), so hence both the tags.

Comment: Why not just use a Linux IDE ?

Comment: Did you look at [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)?

Comment: _lack of breakpoints_? You should really learn to use the Linux tools before trying a very complicated cross-platform workaround for a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Netbeans allows to compile, run and debug c++ on remote machines.

Comment: @PaulR : I can't say I'm sure but since we connect to remote linux machines, i think it will have some sort of impact on the memory if we all start using IDE's on linux. We connect to the linux machines via our laptops, hence I wanted to give an IDE via windows a shot.

Comment: @Galik && Bigiansen : Thank you for your comments, I will browse more about using Eclipse and netbeans. I had the wrong notion that Eclipse was restricted to the usage of Java. Clearly, i was wrong :)

Comment: @Useless : I agree, but i have to deliver something important in a short frame of time and linux is new to me, so while **I** **WILL** be trying to get used to linux tools quickly, I could do with a complicated workaround that can help me get my work done quickly.

Comment: Visual C++ for Linux in Visual Studio works well and I've been using it for cross-platform development since it's release back in 2016 : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/. If you have an existing VS solution, the simplest approach it to add side-by-side projects for the Linux target and add the source files into them (copy 'n paste). Same source, same structure. Bracket your Windows/Linux specific code sections with some `#ifdefs` and hit build.